# How do I register a Google cloud application?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

In the Google plus Quick Start documentation:

[Google Plus Quick Start Enable Google plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php#step_1_enable_the_google_api)

It states that a form needs to be filled out to register the app.  But I can't find anything to click on to register the app.  I'm wondering if the Google Console layout has changed, and the documentation hasn't been updated?  I did a search on the word, "register" but didn't find anything.

The side bar on the left that I see has a list like this:

```
Overview
----------
APIs and auth
    Credentials
    Consent Screen
    Push
```

That's what my Google Console screen looks like.  I don't see any menu item for `Register App`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

True, that part changed a bit. What you need to do now is to go to "Credentials" and create a new Client ID there. You will then find the necessary Client ID and Client secret listed on that page.

[image: Credentials]

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Actually, when I've created a new project, it seems to automatically create some new credentials without me having to click the `Create New Client ID` button.  I do need to change the Redirect URIs if needed.

Comment: Just make sure to also adjust your Consent screen.